# Something sends emails to email@example.com permanently

Tags: email, freebsd, dovecot, spam, sendmail

I'm watching multiple lines in maillog for the last few days

```
Feb 26 06:00:17 d3355 sm-mta[2682]: x1L5tNWu013205: to=<email@example.com>, delay=4+21:04:54, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=21630740, relay=example.com., dsn=4.0.0
Feb 26 06:00:17 d3355 sm-mta[2682]: x1L5mAV2013049: to=<email@example.com>, delay=4+21:12:07, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=21630752, relay=example.com., dsn=4.0.0
Feb 26 06:00:17 d3355 sm-mta[2682]: x1L5OBhg012679: to=<email@example.com>, delay=4+21:36:06, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=21720764, relay=example.com., dsn=4.0.0
Feb 26 06:00:17 d3355 sm-mta[2682]: x1L3Y1dP011346: to=<email@example.com>, delay=4+23:26:16, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=21990723, relay=example.com., dsn=4.0.0
```

As a result I have tons of "Returned mail" feedbacks in my mailbox.
I can't figure out what process does it.
How can I detect and stop it?
I have FreeBSD + sendmail + dovecot

Answer (score 1):

1. Check what `mailq` command reports about messages in sendmail (outgoing) queue
2. Check all log entries related to specific queue id e.g. `x1L5tNWu013205`
   In `x1L5tNWu013205` case initial log entries should be 4 days 21 hours old
   `sm-mta` log entries may lead to msa log entries (sendmail process sending user mail to main sendmail daemon)

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you give more details about second part? i found tons of files in /var/spool/mqueue. my first question, can I remove all data here? I also found some details about my original question and continue investigation, so thanks again, the answer is very helpful